# Color picker as app in Yosemite

Tags: macos, applescript

As of upgrading to yosemite the apple script `choose color` no longer works. The color picker app launches but the eyedropper doesn't function. Does anyone know a work-around for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bug, but there's a strange workaround. After highlighting the *Eyedropper* icon, click and drag on the color next to it on the left.

[image]

Comment: Nice find! Strangely, the eye dropper will appear for 1-2 seconds after you quit but it's futile, by then the dialog has disappeared and the color lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can download application [Color Picker](http://www.blastframe.com/share/ColorPicker.zip) and save follow AppleScript code as an Service(use Automator to create).

```
on run {input, parameters}
    --click button to select color from screen
    tell application "System Events"
        set isRunning to (name of processes) contains "Color Picker"
        if not isRunning then
            set front_app to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
            --open Color Picker
            do shell script "open -a \"Color Picker\""
            delay 2
            display dialog "Application Color Picker is running now, please try again" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        else
            tell process "Color Picker"
                tell window 1
                    click checkbox 1
                end tell
                set frontmost to true
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
    return input
end run
```